# How can I change x labels to years?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a data https://www.kaggle.com/rodolfofigueroa/spotify-12m-songs

I wanted to analyze How was the mood of the songs released initially compared with those released in 2020?
So I went for plotting year on the x-axis and valence on the y-axis.
NOTE- Valence is the Measurement of how positive a track sounds, from 1 (extremely positive) to 0 (extremely negative).

I created this data frame to check the first 20 values and when I am plotting it on the x-axis I am getting row numbers.
sorted_df_year['valence'][:20].plot(kind='bar',figsize=(20,5))

My question is how can I change the x-axis label to years (column present in the dataset)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the expected output is not explicitly stated, I used a bar graph of averages grouped with the x-axis as year. Does it conform to your intended output?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('./data/tracks_features.csv', sep=',')
df.groupby('year')['valence'].mean().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(20,5))
```

[image]

Comment: So you have found out mean and hence grouped for each year which has acted as the data for the graph, am I right?

Comment: I grouped them by year and graphed the averages.

Comment: There is a check mark under the lower triangle in my answer, please check it. If you are unsure, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).